# Mac m1 (apple silicon chip) and docker issues

Tags: docker-compose, apple-m1, tomcat9, macos-monterey

What is the best approach to get mac m1 working with docker?

For testcontainers, I used colima and that worked well consistently with testcontainers and oracle db.

For docker-compose, I have had many issues - intermittent SIG fault with deploying a java spring boot war on tomcat 9 and jdk 8 or jdk 17 images. I have tried using platform linux/amd64 or linux/x86_64. This seems to sometimes work, but the container start-up is much slower too.

Please advise.
Thanks.

Comment: M1 is not x86/64, so they'll be emulated. Poorly. Use M1-specific images or build your own.